# Status 403 for XMLHTTPRequest for Header Ifno

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I have a script running in a web page that successfully accesses (using XMLHTTPRequest)   text or CSV file and retrieves the content from a particular URL on a site that provides membership services to our organization.  They provide the resources for creating the webpages.  If I use the request for Header info it returns a status of 200.   I can use the URL of image (.JPG) files from the same URL folder and create images on my web page.  However if I try a header request with the URL of the JPG file,  I receive a 403 status.    Not sure why I am getting this since I have proven correct syntax in my code, and access to the folder location in other statements for other files. So references to statements reference the SRC for an image in image related statements work, or directly in HTL image tags also work, but not in the HEADER request. BTW.. the request is synchronous.

I tried several different image URLs but all returned the same error.